# psycopg2 copy_expert - static column

Tags: psycopg2, psql

I am trying to insert a large csv file into a PSQL table using `psycopg2 copy_expert`. However, I have 3 constraints:

- The original csv file has 7 columns and I only need to insert 5 of them
- I need to rename the 5 columns that I insert
- I need to add 2 extra columns with static value

I am currently looping on every column on my csv using `DictReader` and then executing an `INSERT INTO` table. However, this is quite slow but I haven't seen any example of `copy_expert` where you can rename a column and add extra columns.

**csv file:**

```
timer;A1;A2;A3;A4;UnitMeasureent
2023-02-22 10:11:00.000000;1.25;2.14;1.00;5.65;eur
2023-02-23 10:11:00.000000;1.12;3.10;1.02;5.65;eur
```

**PSQL table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.data(
    serial_number VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    global_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    a1 double precision,
    a2 double precision,
    a4 double precision,
    unit_measurement varchar(50)
);
```

the `serial_number` column should always `S01` during the insert and the `global_id` `GER`. The be the result post insert should be:

```
serial_number;global_id;a1;A2;a4;unit_measurement
S01;GER;1.25;2.14;5.65;eur
S01;GER;1.12;3.10;5.65;eur
```

Comment: You numbers don't add up. Your CSV file shows 6 columns not 7. You are renaming 4 columns not 5. That means you inserting 6 columns of data not 7.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rename the columns per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

> HEADER

> Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table. On input, the first line is discarded when this option is set to true (or equivalent Boolean value). If this option is set to MATCH, the number and names of the columns in the header line must match the actual column names of the table, in order; otherwise an error is raised. This option is not allowed when using binary format. The MATCH option is only valid for COPY FROM commands.

So either don't the header or if you do set `HEADER true`. Only if you set `MATCH`(present only in Postgres 15+) are the header names matched to the column names. This means you now just need to iterate over the CSV file in a separate operation where you get rid of the columns you don't want and insert the ones you do in order.